# Error when parsing DATETIME from SQLite to java.SQL.Timestamp

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc, datetime-parsing

I am making a desktop windows pc app using java 11 and SQLite 3.30.1. In my sql table "Alarms" i have a date (DATETIME) column and i try to retrieve it using jdbc resultset.getTimestamp(). But i get the following error: "java.sql.SQLException: Error parsing time stamp". 
Since this is an alarm manager i want to store date + time. I also want to be able to substract 2 dates, one from another.
This is my alarm table:

```
CREATE TABLE "alarms" (
"id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
"date"  DATETIME NOT NULL,
"name"  TEXT,
"text"  TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
```

this is my Alarms java class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class Alarms implements Serializable {

private int id;

private Timestamp date;

private String name;

private String text;

public Alarms() {
}

public Alarms(int id, Timestamp date, String name, String text) {
    this.id = id;
    this.date = date;
    this.name = name;
    this.text = text;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Timestamp getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Timestamp date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
}
```

this is my java jdbc method:

```
    public ObservableList<Alarms> getAlarms() {

    alarmsList.clear();
    try {
            s = "SELECT * FROM alarms";

        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(s);
        while (resultSet.next()) {

            Alarms al = new Alarms();
            al.setId(resultSet.getInt(1));
            al.setDate(resultSet.getTimestamp(2)); 
            al.setName(resultSet.getString(3));
            al.setText(resultSet.getString(4));

            alarmsList.add(al);

        }
        return alarmsList;

    } catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

So the question is, how can i store, insert and retrieve Date+time in SQLite using jdbc ? what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching all day i found a solution. In your SQLite table you can use perfectly DATETIME to store date+time.SQLite will store it as String. My table is as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE "alarms" (
"id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
"date"  DATETIME NOT NULL,
"name"  TEXT,
"text"  TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
```

Since SQLite returns a String, you have to use "getString()" on your resultset in java. This string is a Long number like 1588370406005 . 
so i had to add some additional getters and setters to my Alarms java class.
This is my Alarm java class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;


public class Alarms implements Serializable {

private int id;

private LocalDateTime date;

private String name;

private String text;

public Alarms() {
}

public Alarms(int id, LocalDateTime date, String name, String text) {
    this.id = id;
    this.date = date;
    this.name = name;
    this.text = text;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public LocalDateTime getDate() {
    return date;
}

public String getDateStringFormat(){

    return Long.toString(date.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli());

}

public void setDate(LocalDateTime date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public void setDate(String stringDate){

    date= Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(stringDate)).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();

}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
}
```

my JDBC method is:

```
public ObservableList<Alarms> getAlarms() {

    alarmsList.clear();
    try {
            s = "SELECT * FROM alarms";

        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(s);
        while (resultSet.next()) {

            Alarms al = new Alarms();
            al.setId(resultSet.getInt(1));
            al.setDate(resultSet.getString(2));
            al.setName(resultSet.getString(3));
            al.setText(resultSet.getString(4));

            alarmsList.add(al);

        }
        return alarmsList;

    } catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `DATETIME` type in SQLite according to [spec](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

It'll be converted to `NUMERIC`. You may use various functions in request to get what you want: [date & time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: Even if there is no DATETIME type, if you input DATETIME as type in your table, it works. it returns you a string. Indeed i have been using DATE type for long time and it works perfectly. And there is no DATE type. Internally, SQLite transform it into another working type. The thing is to work with dates, is moreless easy and there is a lot of documentation out there. But for storing date + time, there is almost no information.